# Importing alternative header file in code oss on linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, visual-studio-code

I need an alternative header file to [process.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fprintf-fprintf-l-fwprintf-fwprintf-l?view=vs-2019) for `File *` `fprintf((FILE *)values,"%c  %f\n  ", Type, Code);` commands which printing some values to a text file as column values

I am using Linux and Code OSS(vs code open source alternative) which gcc doesn't support `process.h` natively.

I found [subprocess.h](https://github.com/sheredom/subprocess.h.git) and I need add library `gcc` but nor `/usr/include` nor `working directory` clones haven't worked still I am taking  an error

```
    vc1.cpp:16:10: fatal error: subprocess: No such file or directory
   16 | #include <subprocess>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Can I add additional header file on linux for Visual Studio Code and fix this problem.

Additionally, editor suggest edit includepath settings but I think not related

Comment: try #include <subprocess.h> if your file C Header

Comment: That's true, It solved thank you